# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, jersey

You may feel this is a duplicated question, but none of the questions with the same title solve my problems. I am using Jersey 2.0 creating a RESTful web service in Eclipse, I use Tomcat 7.0 as my server, I have the following `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.shop.domain</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have a simple class called Hello:

```
@Path("customers")
public class Hello {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getCustomer() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I have a Jersey library called `jersey`:

[image]

Every time I ran this project, I got error of

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait, you said you have a Jersey library called `jersey`, did you create a `User Library` and name it `jersey`? If so, try to copy your jersey jar files into **WebContent -> WEB-INF -> lib**.

Comment: I'd like to second the recommendation given by @Ebin below. Use Maven. Convert the Eclipse project to Maven, and keep developing it in Eclipse. I've been doing that for a while now, and am happy with this choice.

Comment: i have copied that , and it has copied the jars into the tomcat webapps\projName\WEB-INF\lib too. Now i dont get classnotfoundexception, but i still face the same issue on invoking the service, i get javax.servlet.ServletException: Class [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer] is not a Servlet
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542). Any idea what else is going wrong?

Comment: Hi @Anu, did you solve the issue?:D

Answer (score 20):

I guess this has already been answered, but just wanted to add an extra tip.

For web projects in Eclipse, it is almost always advisable to manage dependencies with Maven. Use a Maven plugin like m2e. Once you add a dependency to your Maven project, it should automatically deploy those libraries to **WEB-INF/lib**. If it does not (for whatever reasons), you can explicit do so:

1. Right-click on your project in **Project Explorer**
2. Select **Properties**
3. Select **Deployment Assembly**
4. If **Maven Dependencies** is not one of the entries, the libraries were not added automatically, so we'll add them now
5. Select **Add**
6. Select **Java Build Path Entries**
7. Select **Maven Dependencies**
8. Click **Finish**

This should add the libraries to **WEB-INF/lib**, although you'd still not see them in the Project Explorer view. But your **ClassNotFoundException** should go away now.

Comment: Saved my day too. Eclipse Luna, Java SE 1.8, JAX-RS Jersey 2.17.

Comment: Great points, I was using maven, but didn't have it part of the path when I converted the maven project to a dynamic web project :( Was troubleshooting this way longer than I want to admit... thanks for saving me :)

Comment: Looks like if you right click on the project -> Maven -> Update Project... then this clears out this setting too, which makes you have to reset it up.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Worked like Charm. Thank you so much

Answer (score 8):

While all of the above could apply (Eclipse is not the most credible application) make sure that you have double checked your maven dependencies. You should note that for jersey 2.19 I had to add these 2 maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: adding "org.glassfish.jersey.containers" helped me to solve the error.

Answer (score 2):

Message is simple enough to identify the root cause the Jersey libraries are not in classpath.

***The first thing you should check that weather do you have the dependencies for jersey defined in you pom.xml or not.
if not here are the dependencies you can define. if it is already defined in pom.xml, ignore adding dependencies in your pom.xml***.

```html
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Solution – Add Jersey Library in Deployment Assembly**

**1. Right-click on your project in Project Explorer**

**2. Open your project’s deployment assembly configuration.**

[image]

**3. Add Build path jar files in assembly so that they can be added to
    lib folder in final war file.**

[image]

**4. Updated assembly will look like this.**

[image]

**Click ok.
Now you are good to go.**

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem with Eclipse. My project which has a very similar setup - `Jersey 2`, `Tomcat 7`. I'm running tomcat from inside eclipse, and it seems that somewhere along the way eclipse sort of forgot how to deploy the libraries to tomcat properly.

I tried deploying my war file manually to tomcat and starting it via `startup.sh` and it worked fine, but if I start it up via eclipse I get my web content but the Jersey classes aren't there so the REST API doesn't work. My login servlet works fine, just not the jersey bit. The console has the same error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

on startup. So it must be a problem with how eclipse deploys code to tomcat. I tried going into eclipse servers and clearing the work dir, didn't do anything. (not that it would, for missing classes).

The only thing that worked was going to my Servers config in Eclipse and deleting my tomcat entry then creating a new one. I did that and it fixed it straight away.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the fix was doing this:

```
Right click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries ->
Add Library... -> Server Runtime -> Apache Tomcat v7.0 -> Finish
```

Another step i did was to import stuff in Maven but it wasnt neccessary as it is running fine without it too.

But here it is if it helps anyone

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

putting servlet jars in WEB-INF/lib just did things more complicated as the Exception Message got more complicated and irrelevant

EDIT: oh what also does help is to do an Update Project on your Maven Project.

Answer (score 0):

I am also observing the same issue. I am using tomcat8 with Maven. If I build Dynamic Web Project and add all libraries manually, project works fine but if I use Maven, it gives following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey REST Service] in web application [/EmployeeManagement] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have added following maven dependencies in pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: doesn't look like a solution to me, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the **jersey jar** files in **WEB-INF/lib** should work.

If you're not able to put your jersey jar files in **WEB-INF/lib**, try copy pasting it manually by going through your workspace and restart eclipse ! That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add Jersey library to the build path under library

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaxrsri20sourcesjar.htm        get it from here

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, I had the same problem and @Edin's answer worked, however I was using *IntelliJ*. So I thought I would add a way to do this for Intellij (for future people like me):

1. File
2. Project Structure
3. Artifacts
4. You should have an Artifact there named after your project, select it
5. On the right, you will see a list *Available Elements*
6. Select all the available elements, right click, then select the option that adds them to the **WEB-INF/Lib**